# Css 3 Flexible box layout

Tags: css, z-index, nav

With the CSS bellow I can center every li inside of an ul. The problem is that i can't see the li elements. They're under the ul. I know that they're centered because i saw it in Chrome Developer Tools.

```
nav ul {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

z-index doesn't work at all...

UPDATE: I've remove float: left and it worked!

Thank you.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to your question and then mark it accepted.But you must wait a day before you can mark it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a fixed height to the ul.